# React import folder navigation

Tags: reactjs, directory, directory-structure

I am trying to import images from an assets folder in my src folder in my react app but for some reason the path is not being recognised.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
|src
 |Assets
 |Common
 |Components
```

I am trying to import the image located in the assets folder from the components folder. I was able to import from my common folder to files in the components folder by doing the following:

```
import * as Constants from '../Common/Constants';
```

However following this same structure for loading images has not worked

```
<img src = '../Assets/myimg.png'></img>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're providing the image source based on your React app's location, which is neither related to web application's root location, nor **media** or **static** files locations (to be configured), so the browser will not know how to render it. Depending on what server you use (*nginx*, *Express*) you have to configure your **static** and/or **media** files and then specify in your image source based on how you configured.

In your present situation you can do the following:

Import

```
const reactImage = require("../Assets/myimg.png");
```

And then use it:

```
<img src={reactImage.default} />
```

If you had media files already configured on your server and properly resolving, it would be just

```
<img src="/media/Assets/myimg.png" />
```

Assuming **media** location is already configured and is pointing to the parent directory of your **Assets**.

In your example you were assuming the relative path of your React import and the image source hardcoded into image tag are same, but they are actually not.